# D3 - Stacked bar chart, show all values in tooltip

Tags: d3.js

I have a stackblitz here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/bar-tooltip?embed=1&file=src/app/bar-chart.ts&hideNavigation=1

When you hover over the bars the tooltip shows the value for that section of the stacked bar.

Is it pssible to hover anywhere on the bar and show all 3 values in the tooltip.

Comment: you group/color by type, you need to group by bar and put a tooltip on those groups, reorder your data by bar and generate the rects, then you have the needed data as datum to your `g`. Look in the answer I have given for a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach to do that:

In the mouseover function, use the bound data's `data` attribute to fetch all the key values.

```
.on("mousemove", (d:any)=>{
    var html = '';
    that.keys.forEach(function (k) {
      html += k + ': ' + d.data[k] + '<br/>';
    });
    d3.select('.chart-tooltip')
        .html(html.trim())
});
```

And for the above to work, I assigned the keys to a variable like this:

```
private keys = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

Also tweaked the CSS a bit:

```
.chart-tooltip{
  background: red;
  color: white;
  width: 80px;
  height: auto;
}
```

And here's a fork of your code with the above changes:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/bar-tooltip-zcqvvt?file=src/app/bar-chart.ts

Hope this helps.